# Form validation by group using Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, field, formvalidation.io

This is a form I need to validate. Its a Day Group.

[image]

I need to save fields value based on day group. For example on Monday group, I need to enter values in Input1, input2 and check any of the options Checkboxes (Required fields). On clicking save button I need to check Input1, input2 are not null and one check box in options must be selected. Saving time at least one group is selected with above 3 values. At a  time I can save multiple Groups.

I need to check the required fields. I only want to check required fields based on group. Can anyone help me to validate fields based on group using Jquery ?

Comment: provide the code that you have tried so far and where you actually are getting stuck with it

Comment: I am taking these items as 5 objects using javascript. I am able to save if data is entered properly.
 object1 contains input1 value,input2 value and option checked box checked value.( I only need to show required filed  message when 3 values in a particular group is not entered)For example if i enter input1 field value only and didn't check any one of the check box or didn't 
 enter any value in input2 in monday group. At that time i have to show a message that "all three field value are required for each group".

Comment: Let's start from the beginning - what have YOU tried? Where is the code YOU wrote as your baseline? This is an online community to HELP people, not to become voluntary freelancers.

Comment: $("#btnSave").click(function () {var objects = []; var group1 = {Input1: $("#txt11").val(),Input2: $("#txt12").val(),Options: $(".group1:checked").val()};var group2 = {Input1: $("#txtinput21").val(), Input2: $("#txtinput22").val(), Options: $(".group2:checked").val()};-- added two gopu1 and group2 to objects[] $.ajax({url:"",data: JSON.stringify({ dataPass: objects }),success: function (msg) {  }});